# Conditional median with or-clause

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, median, or-condition

In another forum, I found a way to make a conditional median calculation in Excel work like this:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(and(BN8:BN229<44,BN8:BN229>0),BM8:BM229))}
```

...becomes...

```
{=MEDIAN(IF($BN$8:$BN$229<44,IF(BN8:BN229>0,$BM$8:$BM$229)))}
```

...and works (due to the nested if-statements).

However, I need to do the same with an or-clause. How, would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Already found a way:
    {=MEDIAN(IF($BN$8:$BN$229<44,$BM$8:$BM$229,IF(BN8:BN229>0,$BM$8:$BM$229)))}